# Find Text after a String and Paste This at the Start of the Email

Tags: vba, outlook

I have an online form that is filled out by customers that is then sent by email using a standard template. When we send replies we are manually entering in the customers name for each reply. What I am looking for is a way to extract the name and insert this at the top of the email.

The name is always prefixed by First Name: "Name".
At the start of the email I would like to then fill the name in, such as Dear "Name",

I know in excel you can take only part of a string using the cell formula: =LEFT(G91, LEN(G91)-5)
Is there any way something similar can be used in Outlook?

I have been unable to find a way to take a particular part of the email body and reference this in an email. Everything I have found online has been focused around exporting to Excel or adding to the end of the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is described here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx#Outlook2007ProgrammingCh17_ParsingTextFromAMessageBody

Untested - Edited - fixed as suggested in comments

```
Sub FwdSelBodyName()
    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objFwd As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strAddr As String
    Dim strName As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objOL = Application
    Set objItem = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
    If Not objItem Is Nothing Then
        strName = ParseTextLinePair(objItem.Body, "First Name:")
        If strAddr <> "" Then
            Set objFwd = objItem.Forward
            objFwd.HTMLBody = "Dear " & strName & objFwd.HTMLBody
            objFwd.Display
        Else
            MsgBox "Could not extract name from message."
        End If
    End If
    Set objOL = Nothing
    Set objItem = Nothing
    Set objFwd = Nothing
End Sub

Function ParseTextLinePair (strSource As String, strLabel As String)
    Dim intLocLabel As Integer
    Dim intLocCRLF As Integer
    Dim intLenLabel As Integer
    Dim strText As String
    intLocLabel = InStr(strSource, strLabel)
    intLenLabel = Len(strLabel)
        If intLocLabel > 0 Then
        intLocCRLF = InStr(intLocLabel, strSource, vbCrLf)
        If intLocCRLF > 0 Then
            intLocLabel = intLocLabel + intLenLabel
            strText = Mid(strSource, _
                            intLocLabel, _
                            intLocCRLF - intLocLabel)
        Else
            intLocLabel = _
              Mid(strSource, intLocLabel + intLenLabel)
        End If
    End If
    ParseTextLinePair = Trim(strText)
End Function
```

Comment: After a little bit of editing it is now working as desired.
 `dim strAddr` was missing and changing `objFwd.HTMLBody = "Dear " & strName & HTMLBody` to `objFwd.HTMLBody = "Dear " & strName & objItem.HTMLBody` was needed. However whenever this is done it defaults all the text to Times New Roman rather than all my font settings which are set to Calibri. Any Idea how to ensure the formatting settings are kept when using this?

Comment: @damien-walker You will have to investigate further. It may need something like objFwd.HTMLBody = "<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:11'>" & "Dear " & strName </p>" & objFwd.HTMLBody

Comment: @damien-walker Try objFwd.Body = "Dear " & strName & objFwd.Body rather than objFwd.HTMLBody = "Dear " & strName & objFwd.HTMLBody